# Vuetify Send data from form with Axios

Tags: forms, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify in my VueJs project and I need to send data from my form in which I am uploading a file (CSV) and got some number inputs. I need to do that with Axios.

I've tried to do something but always got a 404.

This is my Vuetify code:

```
<v-form>
    <v-container>
        <v-row>
            <v-file-input
                show-size
                counter
                multiple
                label="Nacitaj CSV"
                ref="myfile"
                v-model="files"
            ></v-file-input>
        </v-row>

            <v-row>
                <v-col>
                    <v-text-field
                        type="number"
                        label="zadaj cislo"
                    />
                </v-col>
                <v-col>
                    <v-text-field
                        type="number"
                        label="zadaj cislo"
                    />
                </v-col>
            </v-row>

            <v-row>
                <v-col :cols="2">
                    <v-btn
                        block
                        color="primary"
                        @submit="submitFiles"
                    >
                        Submit
                    </v-btn>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
    </v-container>
</v-form>
```

```
methods: {
        submitFiles() {
            if (this.files) {
                 let formData = new FormData();
                 // files
                 for (let file of this.files) {
                    formData.append("files", file, file.name);
                 }
                 // additional data
                 formData.append("test", "foo bar");
                 axios.post("/about", formData);
            }
```

I've tried the script which I found on internet but it wasn't working; also the script was only for the file.

Comment: 404 = not found, do you have a server running at "/about"?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old but for the next person arriving at this answer, let's take a look at submitFiles function:

```
submitFiles() {
            if (this.files) {
                 let formData = new FormData();
                 // files
                 for (let file of this.files) {
                    formData.append("files", file, file.name);
                 }
                 // additional data
                 formData.append("test", "foo bar");
                 axios.post("/about", formData);
            }
```

the first `if` is checking if `files` is not empty. `files` is part of the model. If there are files it creates a new object to hold the Form data (`formData`).

Then it will loop the files object and append the files to the object holding the form data and after that it will append a field called `test` with the value `foo bar` and make a post request to `/about` in the domain you're serving your page sending the form data object as the body. If you're getting a 404 it should mean that `about` doesn't exist.